# Uml representation of forward declaration + std::vector<std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, uml, c++14, c++17

What is the uml representation of the following c++ class:

```
class A;

class B: public std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>
{
}
```

and

```
class C : public std::enable_shared_from_this<C>
{
}
```

Comment: The Legendary Jon Skeet has already provided an answer :)

Comment: It is not the same. Check that in the first example we have a forward declaration of A. In the second one we have the same inherit class C. It is not duplicated my question is not about template.

Comment: Forward declaration won't be represented in UML, it makes no sense since it is an implementation detail.